# Is there a good lower bound for the integral $\int_G x^2 \,dx\,dy$ in terms of $\int_G x \,dx\,dy$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, estimation, integral-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $G\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be some bounded domain such that $\overline{G}\subset (0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$. I want to estimate the integral $\int_G x^2 \, d \lambda$ from below in terms of $\int_G x\, d\lambda$. Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (as was suggested by Daniel Schepler below), we have:

$$ \int_G x^2 \, d\lambda\geq \frac{ \left(\int_G x \, d\lambda\right)^2}{\int_{G}1 \,d\lambda}. $$

My question is: Is there a better estimate?

Best wishes

Comment: If having a bound in terms of both $\int_G x \, dx \, dy$ and $\int_G dx\, dy$ is good enough, you could use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you think there is a better estimate than Cauchy-Schwarz, or is it the best we can do?

Comment: Note that if $\overline{G} \subseteq (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon) \times \mathbb R$ then 

$$\frac{\int_G x^2 d\lambda}{\frac{ \left(\int_G x d\lambda\right)^2}{\int_{G}1 \,d\lambda}}\leq \frac{(1+\epsilon)^2}{(1-\epsilon)^2}$$
so your bound is pretty good in this case. Also, if the projection on $(0, \infty)$ of your domain is very small, the C-S inequality is "almost" equality. But if this projection is large, you are far of equality... In that case, if you want a better inequality, you need to split $$G= \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty G_k \\G_k=G \cap (\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n}]\times \mathbb R$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There certainly isn't a uniform bound for all domains: If $G=(0,1/n)\times[0,1]$ then the ratio between the integral of the square and the integral without the square tends to zero as $n\to\infty$. $\int_Gx^2\,d\lambda$ is much smaller than $\int_G x\,d\lambda$. In fact, the first integral is $n^{-3}/3$ and the second one is $n^{-2}/2$.

Comment: This answer doesn't say that no bound exists; it just says that any bound has to be in terms of the bounds of the integral, which OP already knew.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll edit the answer.